# Why do I have random ridge lines appearing on my otherwise flat geometry? Please help!

Tags: modeling, geometry

I'm having an issue with strange and subtle ridges appearing in my flat geometry. At least, I think it's flat. It's apparent in final renders and when I look around at it MatCap view. When I switch to wireframe I don't see an edge which could be the cause of a ridge. This is a total mystery to me. I'm new to Blender so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. I hope someone is available to help me with this issue. Thank you so much[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you Boolean or knife tool in the shapes for those dials? If so, Blender is connecting some of the vertices  of the dial's edge to the edge of the panel. The smooth shading on the panel is trying to work with an ngon and semi-random edges. Try selecting all the faces on the panel, right clicking, and press Shade Flat. If that isn't the result you were looking for, try Mesh,Clean Up, Split Non-Planer Faces, Split Concave Faces, make Planer Faces (general clean up junk). Then select all the edges of the effected part and press ctrl b and drag out slowly. This will add a bevel which can help shading problems.

Comment: Zach! Oh wow, thank you SO MUCH! Selecting the faces then Shade Flat solved the problem. What an easy and straight-forward fix too! I'm so happy right now! Thank you – I appreciate you! Yeah, I boolean'ed those shapes for the dials.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help ya out. That's really nice looking for early work btw. Keep it up!